# Remove duplicate type signature in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, refactoring, c++14, type-signature

I have the following code snippet in C++14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> using Func = function<T>;
template <typename T> using Epct = Func<void (T)>;
template <typename... Ts> using PartGen = Func<void (Ts...)>;

template <typename T> struct RevEpct : public RevEpct<decltype(&T::operator())> {};
template <typename T, typename C> struct RevEpct<void (C::*)(T) const> {
  using Type = T;
};

template <typename F> auto foo(F func) {  // F: Epct<Epct<PartGen<int, double>>>
  using T = typename RevEpct<F>::Type;  // T: Epct<PartGen<int, double>>
  using U = typename RevEpct<T>::Type;  // U: PartGen<int, double>
  return [=] (auto ...vs) {
    func([=] (U u) {
      u(vs...);
    });
  };
}

int main() {
  foo([] (Epct<PartGen<int, double>> k) {
    k([] (int x, double y) {
      // do something here
      cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    });
  })(42, 42.5);
}
```

Every time I am calling `foo`, I have to write the same type signature (in this case `<int, double>`) twice. For some reason I **cannot just write a wrapper function that takes the `(int, double) -> void` lambda as argument**. Thus, I am looking for solution in either these two ways:

- Is there anyway to omit one of these two signatures and let the compiler infer another one **only by the original `foo` function**? I have tried to replace the argument of the outer lambda with `auto k` but that will not work.
- Is there anyway to write a macro that might be used like this:

  ```
  FOO(k, [] (int x, double y) { /* ... */ })
  ```

  or like this:

  ```
  FOO(k, int, x, double, y) { /* ... */ }
  ```

  I am doubting that whether it is possible to implement the second version.

Also, I really hope that the macro would work well with any number of arguments. Thanks.

Comment: I ... really can't tell what you're asking or what the problem is. All these weird aliases don't help either.

Comment: I'm trying to get through all those function calls, but I'm not smart enough this late in the day.

Comment: Could [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kAsFFVymHsJ63KmM) work for you? Just got rid of a couple of aliases and put an auto in the right place to avoid typing twice the type list.

Comment: @skypjack This is something that I need, but my clang shipped with macOS do not support gnu++2a flag. I am looking for a way to solve it in at most c++1z.

Comment: @Barry The global aliases are just helping to understand the type of `k` which passed as an argument into `foo`, and `T` and `U` is vital because `U` is the type of argument which passed into the `func` callback. I have to provide this info to compiler or it would complain to me.